# How to re-size partitions without space directly in font of them?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 7. The problem is that when I first installed Ubuntu I didn't really expect it to become my main operating system so I gave it small partitions naively thinking that if I ever needed more space it would just take more automatically. Now I am faced with this issue, I have over 250 gb of free space but it is not anywhere near my root partition. [image: Partition Now]

I tried live booting from a usb and turning off swap which allowed me to make the partition of /dev/sda4 bigger but, I could not figure out how to make the root or the home any bigger. I am guessing because it was not directly in line with the new open spots. As most of you can probably tell I am using gparted to make all of the partitions move. If it makes any different I had a lot of issue's with raid setups back when I started but those are all fixed, namely I just don't use my ssd with ubuntu, because of these issue's though I had to create my own partitions in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in steps.

First add the unallocated space to the extneded partition, sda4 -> apply changes

Next you have to move your partitions one at a time until the unallocated space is adjacent to your / partition. You have to do it is steps -> move a partition, apply changes ... move a partition -> apply changes

Comment: It gave the warning, the command that was giving to gparted may cause issue's booting and data loss, so I stayed away. It will be fine if I like inch worm my partitions back but don't leave any space between them?

Comment: As the warning indicates, data loss is always a possibility. Back up your data first. Your choices are to leave it as is, risk resizing, or re-format your hard drive and re-install.

Comment: I backed up everything but what's the probability of losing the rest of my data? if I were to re-format and re-install is there a way to have all of my applications re-install the same way,I'm guessing not, I only ask because I have a couple of annoyingly complicated programs installed.

Comment: Don't re-install...  As long as your computer doesn't run out of power, doesn't get hit by lightning, doesn't get bumped off the table, gets beer thrown all over it while doing this, you're safe...  ;-)